# Comparing runtimes of different bases to some power

Tags: runtime, big-o

In terms of runtime how does 2^3logn compare to 6^logn.

The initial problem was comparing n^3 to 6^logn and I changed n^3 to 2^3logn to make the runtimes more comparable. It can also be simplified to 8(2^logn). But I'm not sure if I can simplify it further and which one is faster.

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer help you understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *2^(3logn)*, then use exponent rules to see that

*2^(3logn) = (2^3)^logn = 8^logn*.

This should reveal all you need to know.